# UsersContext database in Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the MVC, when i create a new MVC 4 app, inside a model folder there is file name called AccountModels.

inside that i saw code that deals with databse.

```
 public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Do i need to create a new EDMX model/ DataBase? or i can use this to generate Edmx model?

and there is no DB in that new project.

Answer (score 1):

This is a code first model used for your Membership database.  You can certainly use it for your own Data model as well, but you cannot use it as a basis for an EDMX model.  You will have to create a separate EDMX file for that.

Code first and EDMX are not compatible.